# Get nesting of overlapping ranges

Tags: php, logic

I have a sorted array of ranges:

```
$events = Array(
Array('start' => 1, 'end' => 5),
Array('start' => 2, 'end' => 3),
Array('start' => 4, 'end' => 5),
Array('start' => 6, 'end' => 7),
Array('start' => 6, 'end' => 8),
Array('start' => 6, 'end' => 9));
```

and my goal is to find the nesting level of overlapping ranges (exclusive). For imaging this example:

```
n    |                                       
e  3 |                       .............   
s  2 |       .....   .....   :........   :   
t  1 |   ....:...:...:...:   :....   :   :   
.    |   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   
---------1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10---
```

here is my broken code:

```
foreach($events as $k1 => &$evt1) {
    foreach($events as $k2 => &$evt2) {
        if($k1 == $k2)
            continue;

        if(is_overlapping($evt1['start'],$evt1['end'],$evt2['start'],$evt2['end'])) {
            if(!isset($evt1['l']))
                $evt1['l'] = Array();

            if(!in_array($k2, $evt1['l'])) {
                $evt1['l'][] = $k2;
            }
        }

    }
}

foreach($events as $k => &$evt) {
     echo "{$evt['start']}-{$evt['end']}: " . (count($evt['l']) + 1) . "\n";
}
```

and there is an output (which is invalid in first row) for this sample data:

```
1-5: 3 <-- should be 2
2-3: 2
4-5: 2
6-7: 3
6-8: 3
6-9: 3
```

I can't figure it out. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does this array come from?

Comment: This is just a simplified example, i need to arrange items on screen depending on this nesting.